# How to use Google Docs as Backend for Website?

Tags: html, css, spreadsheet, google-docs, backend

I am building a site at the moment that requires data to be updated by my client. I only know how to front end develop a simple HTML/CSS site, but giving them the possibility to update this table without messing with the code would be the best case scenario.

Essentially I have built and styled a table in my document, however, I was wondering if it was possible to extract information from a google doc (such as a spreadsheet) to automatically update the fields of the table on the site I'm building.

The table is for shows, so the basic columns are Date, Venue, Info, City, Country, RSVP

Mostly requires text input, however the RSVP is a link to a Facebook event page, or external webpage that sells tickets, so the RSVP column would have a link that would need to be updated in the table.

Please advise on the simplest way I can go about this.

One last thing, is there a way to set a limit on # of rows that appear?

Comment: There is definitely an API, BUT mysql would be much easier to use with some backend language (PHP, Node, etc).  Another option would be to use something like Firebase.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do this. There is a 3rd party product called Cloud Snippets (www.cloudward.com). Snippets use a tag language called EASE (open source) that access Google Sheets and Docs - This is all embedded into your normal HTML/css page. Then very easy to deploy to your web site. Any changes to the Google Docs get automatically posted to your web page.

How Snippets work - the EASE code is preprocessed - in the below examples, the Google Sheet is read and embedded into your HTML page - the HTML page is displayed as normal - thus, you can write HTML/CSS and embed EASE tags to open sheets, embed docs, and format all around these.

Examples, in answer to your questions:

1) Format rows from a sheet. This example takes columns named name,address,city,state and formats the rows into a table.

```
<# start list for googlesheet "employees"; #>

<# start header #>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Address</th>
        <th>City</th>
        <th>State</th>
    </tr>
<# end header #>

<!-- Each row in the sheet will be formatted as defined in start-end row block -->
<# start row #>
    <tr>
        <td><# Name #></td>
        <td><# Address #></td>
        <td><# City #></td>
        <td><# State #></td>
    </tr>
<# end row #>

<# start footer #>
</table>
<# end footer #>

<# no results #>
You had no rows in your sheet
<# end no results #>

<# end list #>
```

2) filter rows from a sheet. Update the start list to use a filter

```
<# start list for googlesheet "employees"; 
   include when State = "CA";
#>
```

3) Include Google Doc content. This will pull the Google and embed into your web page

```
<# include google doc "Google Doc Name"; #>
```

4) To limit the number of rows on a page - you can also page (display 20 rows per page in the below example)

```
<# start list for googlesheet "employees"; 
   show 20 rows per page;
#>
```